# Generating function of random variable - plus constant and multiply by constant

Tags: probability

Let $g_X(t)$ will be generated function of random variable. 
What is generating function for $Y=X+3$ ? And What is generating function for $Z=2X$ ?

We know that $g_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)x^k $. It is definition  from my lecture.

Let $C=3$ will be constant random variable. $P(X=3)=1$ and $P(X\neq 3)=0$ Then $g_{X+C}(t)=g_X(t)g_C(t)=g_X(t)x^3$.

$g_{Z}(t)=g_{X+X}(t)=g_X(t)g_X(t)=(g_X(t))^2$

I am not sure about this solution - first of all I don't know if constant variable is independent with any random variable.  Moreover, I don't know if random variable is independent with self.

Comment: PS: $g_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=k) \color{crimson}{t}^k$ There is no $x$ involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for $g_{X+C}$ is ok. (you should say $P(C=3)=1$). 
As $X$ and $C$ are independent you get the conclusion.

For the second it does not work since $X$ and $X$ are not independent.
Instead you may use $P(Z=2k)=P(X=k)$ and $P(Z=2k+1)=0$.
Hint: You only get even powers of $t$.

Later edit: Let me add (from my comment below) the following more conceptual method to do these computations. One has $$g_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)t^k = {\Bbb E}(t^X). $$
From this : 
$$g_Z(t)={\Bbb E}(t^Z)= {\Bbb E}(t^{2X}) ={\Bbb E}((t^2)^X) = g_X(t^2)$$
Similarly 
$$g_Y(t)={\Bbb E}(t^Y)= {\Bbb E}(t^{X+3}) =t^3{\Bbb E}(t^X) = t^3g_X(t)$$

Comment: Firstly, Why $C$ and $X$ are independent ? Is it about, that $P(X=k, C=3)= P(X=k)\cdot P(C=3)$ and $P(X=k, C\neq 3) = P(X=k)\cdot P(C\neq 3)$ Yeah ?

Comment: Yes that is quite ok as a proof. You could also simply say that $P(Y=k+3)=P(X=k)$ and use this to construct the generating function for $Y$ (but you will get the same result)

Comment: I am trying use series to compute $g_Y(t)$. Look, $g_Y(t)=g_{X+3}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k-3)x^k = x^3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k-3)x^k-3 =x^3 \sum_{k=-3}^{\infty}P(X=k)x^k\neq x^3g_X(t)$ Where am I wrong ?

Comment: I think that our variable $X$ reach only natural values. yeah ?

Comment: $g_Y(t)=\sum_{k\geq 0} P(Y=k) x^k = \sum_{k\geq 3} P(X=k-3)x^k = \sum_{m\geq 0} P(X=m) x^{m+3} = x^3 g_X(t)$ (better change name of variables when substituting $m=k-3$)  [and yes $X$ only takes non-negative values so $Y$ only takes values from 3 and up]

Comment: Ok, so in second case $Z=2X$ reach non-zero values only for even $k$. So, $g_Z(t)=g_X(t^2)$. Yeah ?

Comment: Exactly! Perfect answer. There is by the way a 'magic' trick which allows these calculations: $g_Z(t) = E(t^Z)=E(t^{2X})=E((t^2)^X)=g_X(t^2)$ and $g_Y(t)=E(t^Y)=E(t^{X+3})=t^3 E(t^X)=t^3g_X(t)$ (but this necessitates a rather good understanding of how to take expectations).